# solc --bin "faucet.sol" is not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethereum, solidity

I try to compile my .sol file with `solc --bin`, but Terminal shows me "faucet.sol is not found".
The problem is that file exist in that location. I try to move them to other directory, but effect is the same.

I'm just added a screenshot which presents operation which I tried to accomplish.

[image]

I will be very grateful for some hint.

Comment: Most likely faucet.sol contains the line `import "faucet.sol"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. Solution is create a file in a root location `~` and run command

```
sudo solc --bin faucet.sol
```